# Suggestions for debugging a VB component?

Tags: debugging, exception, vb6, components

I don't have any experience with VB code. But I do know I have a problem with a VB app which hangs in a ocx of his. I can see in windbg that it throws the c000008f exception over and over again and i know that it's just the VB exception handling and it has nothing to do with the "Floating Point In-exact Result" hardware exception (it was just Microsoft's 'brilliant' way of implementing it).

So, the problem. How do I find out what the problem really is ? I don't have Visual Studio installed here, but I do have on my laptop VS 2010 Express installed. Still, I don't think that will work either, i need the Pro version to debug this kind of stuff.

Also, I enabled logging in the problem app and these are the last lines I get:

.............
(bla bla bla)
.............

[COVEControls] [00204] [00008.912] <-               slbChart.ctl : Sub AddItem : (Label=DataObjs, Value=0, Color=, LabelColor=) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00205] [00008.912] ->               slbChart.ctl : Sub AddItem : (Label=Conts, Value=1, Color=, LabelColor=) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00206] [00008.912] ->                   slbChart.ctl : Sub LayoutChart : () : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00207] [00008.912] <-                   slbChart.ctl : Sub LayoutChart : () : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00208] [00008.912] <-               slbChart.ctl : Sub AddItem : (Label=Conts, Value=1, Color=, LabelColor=) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[Cove] [00116] [00009.026] ->   frmMain.frm : Sub COVE1_StatusMsg : (statMsg=Getting Card Information (reading total and free data space)) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[Cove] [00117] [00009.026] <-   frmMain.frm : Sub COVE1_StatusMsg : (statMsg=Getting Card Information (reading total and free data space)) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00209] [00008.948] <-           COVE.ctl : Sub SetSizeBars : () : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00210] [00008.949] ->           COVE.ctl : Sub DrawPie : (pic=, shp0=, shp1=, pctFree=0.9222) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00211] [00008.950] ->               COVE.ctl : Sub DrawLayer : (pic=, shp=, pct=7.779998E-02, color1=32768, color2=128) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00212] [00008.950] <-               COVE.ctl : Sub DrawLayer : (pic=, shp=, pct=7.779998E-02, color1=32768, color2=128) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00213] [00008.950] ->               COVE.ctl : Sub DrawLayer : (pic=, shp=, pct=7.779998E-02, color1=32768, color2=128) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00214] [00008.950] <-               COVE.ctl : Sub DrawLayer : (pic=, shp=, pct=7.779998E-02, color1=32768, color2=128) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00215] [00008.950] ->               COVE.ctl : Sub DrawLayer : (pic=, shp=, pct=7.779998E-02, color1=32768, color2=128) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

[COVEControls] [00216] [00008.950] <-               COVE.ctl : Sub DrawLayer : (pic=, shp=, pct=7.779998E-02, color1=32768, color2=128) : [res = 22%, mem = 2147483647]

....

And it's just repeating DrawLayer ad infinitum. The function which crashes the app succeeds, you can catch a glimpse of the retrieved data for a few secs, then it stops updating the client area and turns to white, mouse pointer is still a hourglass, the app is nonresponsive, after forcing it to close it says in the report details: "hungapp"

So, anyone has a clue of how to find out how it fails ? Do I really need Visual Studio Pro ftw ? (o.o)'

Comment: It was pretty brilliant.  What programmers do with On Error Resume Next is invariably the real problem.  A nice corner case is where it is used in a procedure with a loop and the exit condition trips an error.  No exit.

Answer (score 0):

The .ocx, .ctl, and .frm extensions are all artifacts of vb6/Visual Studio 6. You won't be able to edit this project with the Express Edition currently installed, and you won't be able to buy a current "Pro" to fix this. Visual Studio 6 is no longer available for sale anywhere.

Comment: "VB6 no longer available for sale anywhere??" (1) Nothing is ever removed from [ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/items/__microsoft+visual+6.0)! 2 AFAIK VB6 still available for download on MSDN if you have an MSDN ultimate subscription (I don't). As discussed on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029361/15639)

Answer (score 0):

This exception code is used internally by VB6. This is by design.
Mode info here :
[INFO: Visual Basic Uses Exception Code 0xC000008F as Internal Exception Code](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;232829)
[Old school debugging - VB6 middleware applications - c000008f](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marklon/archive/2006/01/28/518616.aspx)
[Are you aware that you have thrown over 40,000 exceptions in the last 3 hours?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/30/498297.aspx?PageIndex=3)

Comment: Link only answers are bad news.  Case in point: 9 years later, and every one of these links is dead, leaving this answer with nothing of value.